# C++ container with object or with object pointer

Tags: c++

Suppose a lot of objects are going to be put in a std::vector container, and they can be done in the following two ways:

Solution 1

```
 std::vector<MyObject> objArray;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {

        MyObject obj(i);
        objArray.push_back(obj);
    }
```

Solution 2

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<MyObject> > objArray;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {

        MyObject *p_obj = new MyObject(i);
        objArray.push_back(p_obj);
    }
```

So my question here is: are there some criteria that we can follow when choosing one solution from them? Thanks.

Comment: Don't allocate dynamically if you can avoid it.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that even if you *do* have to dynamically allocate, you shouldn't be using `shared_ptr`, but `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @JohnDibling at least he's using smart pointers instead of raw ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I'd choose solution #1, i.e. **`vector<MyObject>`**.

This is simpler than #2 (`vector<shared_ptr<MyObject>>`).

With #1, you can have good *memory **locality***, since `MyObject` instances are stored *sequentially* in memory, which is very *cache-friendly* (and so efficient).
Instead, with #2, the values of the pointers are stored sequentially in the vector, but the objects pointed to are scattered in the heap, so you don't have good locality in this case.

However, there can be exceptions to the general rule. For example, I'd use the `vector<shared_ptr<MyObject>>` option if the instances of `MyObject` are heavy to copy and not cheap to move. In this case, a pointer semantics may help.

Anyway, **when in doubt, measure.** When you are not sure about the performance of some code, just write testing code for the various options you have, and measure the execution time.

Note also that, if you use C++11/14, you can still have pointer semantics, but in a more efficient way than `shared_ptr`: in fact, you can use **`std::unique_ptr`**. `unique_ptr` doesn't have a control block (typical of `shared_ptr`), doesn't have interlocked increment and decrement operations for ref counter, and is in general faster and leaner than `shared_ptr`. If you don't need shared ownership semantics, and you can use a C++11 compiler, `unique_ptr` is a very good alternative to `shared_ptr`.

Note also that you can make `vector<shared_ptr<...>>` slightly more efficient if you use a proper allocator for the object: instead of using raw `new`, consider using **`make_shared`**. It has some advantages, like building the control block and the object in sequential memory locations, so you have better memory locality than a control block created on the heap distant from the controlled object.

Comment: Additional use cases: Inheritance, objects shared heavily across project, copies are actually not that important as `std::vector` can itself be moved

Comment: @Paranaix: Copies are important in C++98/03 (I'm not sure if the OP can use a C++11+ compiler). Moreover, if `MyObject` is a big POD or contains some big POD data member(s), moves may be important and expensive, and something like pointer semantics may come in handy. Anyway, the key point is: _"When in doubt, measure."_. But I think it's safe to assume that the _general guideline_ is to avoid heap allocations if possible, so prefer `vector<MyObject>`. There are of course exceptions to that general rule.

Comment: Of course, but I meant that the vector itself can be moved, not its members. Only the pointers to the allocated heap storaged are swapped so this whole operation doesnt touch the actual objects at all.

Comment: @Paranix: I was thinking of the case when the vector is resized (e.g. when vector has reached full `capacity`, and a new `push_back` call is executed). In this case existing objects are copied to the newly allocated storage (at least in C++98/03, probably they are moved in C++11, assuming that moves are `noexcept`, since `push_back` must offer the strong exception-safety guarantee).

Answer (score 3):

> Are there some criteria that we can follow when choosing one solution from them?

By default you should always choose the simplest and most straight forward way. In your case the first one is the one I'm referring to. If you'll ever need to dynamically allocate with a `boost::shared_ptr` you will know.

Comment: Inheritance is such a case

Comment: @Paranaix: IIRC, there was [a very interesting session](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil) on Channel9 from Going Native 2013, in which Sean Parent described a way to offer a kind of polimorphic behavior without using inheritance. (Probably there was something about that also [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning).)

Answer (score 1):

The choice is simple:

- If the object stored is not polymorph - store the object.
- If the object is polymorph and handles polymorphism internally (a wrapper) store the object.
- Otherwise storing a unique_ptr or shared_ptr is smart

I avoid the last case (unless it is an implementation detail).